# DevExpress: raising GridView events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

Tell me a method by which in C # it would be possible to generate a GridView Event, for example, FocusedRowChanged, like the on ..... methods for WinForms?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an Event like [`FocusedRowChanged`](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.FocusedRowChanged)

You can use this codes

```cs
//using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base;
//the All is ok
public event FocusedRowChangedEventHandler MyFocusedRowChanged;
//Or
public event EventHandler<FocusedRowChangedEventArgs> MyFocusedRowChanged2;
```

If you want to handle the [`FocusedRowChanged`](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.FocusedRowChanged) event,
You can use this codes

```cs
private void YourForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridView.FocusedRowChanged += GridView_FocusedRowChanged;
    this.MyFocusedRowChanged += GridView_FocusedRowChanged;
    this.MyFocusedRowChanged2 += GridView_FocusedRowChanged;
}

private void GridView_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //your code
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

If you want to raise [`FocusedRowChanged`](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.FocusedRowChanged),
You can use this codes

```cs
private void YourForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //gridView.FocusedRowChanged += GridView_FocusedRowChanged;
    //this.MyFocusedRowChanged += GridView_FocusedRowChanged;
    //this.MyFocusedRowChanged2 += GridView_FocusedRowChanged;

    //invoke the handle method
    GridView_FocusedRowChanged(gridView, new FocusedRowChangedEventArgs(-1, gridView.FocusedRowHandle));
    //or change focused row to fire event
    gridView.FocusedRowHandle++;
}
```

Which one do you mean?